# Use `weights` in Estimator Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have implemented implemented a custom Estimator for classification. My `input_fn` function returns `features,labels`. `features` contains the `weights` column and I want to get this inside my estimator to use in my loss function.

```
def my_model(features, labels, mode, params):
"""DNN with hidden layers."""

net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'])
weight = HOW TO GET `weight`FROM `features`
```

**TF Version : 1.4**